# apc.shm_size : right value format

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

On howto and documentation, I generaly find this format

```
apc.shm_size=512M
```

but on one of my server APC 3.0.19 does not like the "M" and crash apache

```
[apc-error] apc_mmap: mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

With the same Debian Lenny, same PHP 5.2.17-dotdeb but apc 3.1.6, it run fine with or without the "M". With apc 3.1.7, I get a warning for each PHP-cli execution or apache restart

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc.shm_size now uses M/G suffixes, please update your ini files in Unknown on line 0
```

Witch apc version need the unit, and wich one doesn't like it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until apc 3.1.4 you don't need to specify "M", it will assume megabytes anyway. Remove "M" suffix. Results can be seen via phpinfo();.

Comment: So under 3.1.4 I don't put M (so APC don't crash) and 3.1.4+ I can put the M so there is no warning?

Comment: Yes, 3.1.4 _and_ higher accepts M :)